# Make loop display posts by alphabetical order

Tags: wp-query, loop

With this loop I am displaying single posts on an archive page. The posts are being sorted by the category 'Banks'. In addition to that, how can I display them in alphabetical order? I've tried using `WP_Query`, but cannot get it to work; it breaks my loop each time.

```
<h3>Banks & Credit Unions</h3>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    if ( in_category( 'Banks' ) ) { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <img  src="<?php the_field( 'biller_logo' )?>">
                <?php the_field( 'biller_name' ) ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php } 
endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: what archive page? is this the main query or a secondary query?

Answer (score 16):

To display posts in descending alphabetical order add this to your `args` array (taken from the wp codex)

```
'orderby' => 'title',
'order'   => 'DESC',
```

To display posts in ascending alphabetical order just switch `DESC` to `ASC`.

So the whole thing would look like:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

### [WP_Query Order by Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Or to use if you do not want to alter the main loop use `get_posts`. WP query alters the main loop by changing the variables of the global variable $wp_query. get_posts, on the other hand, simply references a new WP_Query object, and therefore does not affect or alter the main loop. It would be used in the same way, but changing `$query = new WP_Query( $args );` to something like `$query = get_posts( $args );`.

If you would like to alter the main query before it is executed, you can hook into it using the function pre_get_posts.

Comment: it's not clear from the question if this is an additional query- `pre_get_posts` would be more appropriate in the case of a main query, though the parameters you'd set would be the same.

Comment: indeed, but just get_posts would be simpler. I have updated my answer with get_posts added.

Answer (score 3):

Not the best code i've ever written here but if you want to create a list like:

- A
- America
- B
- Brazil
- Bahamas

You could use..

```
<ul>
                            <?php 
                                query_posts(array( 
                                    'post_type' => 'franchise',
                                    'showposts' => 100,
                                    'orderby'=>'title','order'=>'ASC'
                                ) );  
                                $title_2 = 'A';
                            ?>
                            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
                                <?php
                                    $title = get_the_title();
                                    $title_1 = $title[0];
                                    if ($title_1 !== $title_2){
                                        echo '<li>&nbsp;</li><li><h3>' . $title_1 . '</h3></li><li>&nbsp;</li>';
                                        $title_2 = $title_1;
                                    }
                                ?>                              
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></li>
                                <?php endwhile;?>
                            </ul>
```

Like i said - not the best practice.. but you can tidy up & work from here :)